# Add to a Woo Commerce products search query term/meta with a certain attribute?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This does let me alternate the search query, I just dont know how to update the meta_query to search for a certain attribute (pa_brand in this case).

```
`
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'show_only_products_with_specific_metakey', 10, 2 );

function show_only_products_with_specific_metakey( $meta_query, $query ) {

   $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_pa_brand',
        'value'   => '464',
        'compare' => 'IN'
    );
    
   return $meta_query;

};
```

It always gives 0 results

Answer (score 0):

Seeing `464` as a value, I am assuming it's your attribute term value.

In general, products attributes are taxonomy and attribute values are taxonomy terms so you need to run `Tax_Query` not `Meta_Query`

another mistake here is when you compare with `IN` then you need pass an array value like this `[464]`